# My wifi is now connected to 2 different networks on my Wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ip-address

I tried setting up 2 different IP addresses on my laptop but what ended up happening was now I got my Local Wifi network + the "Unidentified Network" on my Current Connections.

How do undo this? I can't seem to find the remove button. Well actually I did find the button but it doesn't seem to show me the IP Address that was secondly listed.

I followed this when I tried to add a second IP Address: http://www.ehow.com/how_8469143_multiple-ip-addresses-one-computer.html

What it looks like on the Wifi connection:

[image]

From IP Config:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>IPconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : user-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : gateway.2wire.net

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 66-6D-57-DD-3F-1E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR5B125 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 44-6D-57-DD-3F-1E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ecaf:54e4:b4aa:9f01%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.16(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : November-23-13 9:34:04 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : November-26-13 9:34:04 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 174.95.169.38
                                       192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 390360407
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-CA-9E-07-B8-88-E3-46-D2-A5

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : centennialcollege.ca
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-88-E3-46-D2-A5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {A7CEDE2B-1528-4919-A1E2-7151FCBA51EB}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.gateway.2wire.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:34a1:eb2:51a0:56d9(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34a1:eb2:51a0:56d9%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {26327194-D048-48FC-BE3F-5AACDA799597}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\user>
```

Apparently it seems to lag when I start up my computer because it's trying to connect to my wifi.

Answer (score 0):

If your Local Wifi router is using DHCP to issue IP addresses, you can just set that Wireless Connection in windows to use DHCP. Go to the following:

1. Start
2. Control Panel
3. View network status and taks
4. Wireless Network Connection (Your local Wifi)
5. Properties
6. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
7. Properties
8. Click the top Radio buttons in each section: "Obtain an IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically"